# Usage of "auf die Straße hinaustreten"

Tags: word-usage

Verwendet man noch im Deutschen *auf die Straße hinaustreten*?
Wenn ja, in welchem Kontext? Wenn nicht, sagt man eher *auf die Straße gehen*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'hinaustreten' wird im Umgangssprachlichen quasi nicht mehr benutzt. 'Auf die Straße gehen' ist geläufiger - 'hinaus gehen' oder 'aus dem Haus gehen' wird am meisten benutzt.

In Romanen findet man den Begriff 'hinaustreten' noch häufiger.

Answer (score 5):

Das Wort hinaustreten wird eher selten verwendet und gehen klingt in diesem Kontext auch besser.

Laut Duden hat *hinaustreten* eine geringe Häufigkeit, es ist lediglich unter den *Top 100.000 Wörtern* der deutschen Sprache, während *hinausgehen* unter den *Top 10.000* ist und *gehen* unter den *Top 100*.